# Flip Z-Y on import

Tags: import

I would like to retopologize a model.

I import it as an obj.

Unfortunately the model is rotated like this:

[image]

In MeshMixer, it's oriented correctly. In Blender it isn't, so I think I need to change the import settings.

In MeshMixer I have the option "Flip Z-Y on import" activated.

Could anybody tell me how to tell Blender to do the same on import?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but at least it's upright when I choose

```
Forward: -X Forward
Up: Z Up
```

[image]